# Conditional formatting if cells in row are less than header

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to find a way to have a cell in column A turn yellow if any cell in the adjacent row is less than the value of its corresponding header. Please see my [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pKwObseLQWBiotAWlUFbVMWxsQOja2u_fQcDi_oC6BE/edit#gid=0).

I'm trying to use this formula for my conditional formatting: `=COUNTIF(B5:5,"<"&B$4)>=1` but I believe it's stuck on using Cell B4 as the header value for the entire range (instead of C4 for column C, D4 for column D, etc).

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the red option, as you suggested, you should use:

```
=COUNTIF($B5:$H5,"")
```

But you may keep it that option above, so it is red even if there's an orange

[image]

Then, for yellow you can use:

```
=COUNTIF(BYCOL($B5:$H5,LAMBDA(each,each<OFFSET(each,4-ROW(each),0))),TRUE)
```

It checks in each column if the value is smaller than in row 4, and counts the amount of TRUE values

[image]

And green should be by default, I understand. Is it useful?

Comment: I am aware I can use this for range B5:H9, but that's not my issue - I am trying to have range A5:A9 turn yellow if any yellows exist in the adjacent row (which occurs when a cell is less than its header value)

Comment: It's working! I was not aware of the LAMBDA functionality, is that the best way to accomplish this, in your opinion? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! In fact, BYCOL is the function I used to compare "column by column" each cell with the one in row 4. LAMBDA is an auxiliary in this case to allow you to name the cell or range being considered: see the [doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032?hl=en) - Possibly there are similar ways of doing this, but considering that you'll always need to refer to row 4 and count (or sum if you convert TRUEs into 1s), but I don't think they'll be that different in the outcome or time